# Error while making a login authentication page using node express mongoose

Tags: express, mern

i am stuck with this error and neither me nor chatgpt is able to figure out, i have provided my "index.js" file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const userModel = require("./users"); 

const passport = require('passport');
const localStrategy = require("passport-local");

passport.authenticate(new localStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));

router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
res.render("index", {title: 'Express'});
});
router.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next){
  res.send("profile")
});


router.post('/register', function (req, res) {
  var userdata = new userModel({
  username: req.body.username,
  email: req.body.email,
  fullname: req.body.fullname
  });
  userModel.register(userdata, req.body.password)
  .then(function (registereduser) {
  passport.authenticate("local") (req, res, function () { res.redirect('/profile');
  });
  })
  })
  
        router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
          successRedirect: "/profile",
          failureRedirect: "/",
        })), function(req, res) {
          // Send the response only if authentication succeeds
          res.send("profile");
        };
        


router.get("/logout", function(req, res){
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
})
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next(); // Proceed to the next middleware or route handler
  } else {
    // User is not authenticated, redirect to login page
    res.redirect("/");
  }
}
module.exports = router;
```

**i am also providing the error message
**

nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:256
return typeof res.headersSent !== 'boolean'
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headersSent')
at headersSent (D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:256:21)
at D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:92:17
at D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:646:15
at next (D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:216:14)
at Function.handle (D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at Function.handle (D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:181:10)
at app (D:\Backend\appname\node_modules\express\lib\express.js:39:9)
at Object. (D:\Backend\appname\app.js:14:24)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)

Node.js v18.14.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

i have tried using chat gpt and bard both but i wasnt able to figure out the problem, i am stuck since a while please help